# Inverse Hyperbolic Sine Transformation in R for data with many 0's

Tags: r, data-transform

I am trying to use the inverse hyperbolic since (IHS) transformation on a non-normal variable in my dataset. The code that I found on the internet is not working for me. This is what I tried:

```
ihs <- function(col) { 
                transformed <- log((col) +  (sqrt(col)^2+1));
                return(transformed)
                }
```

`col` refers to the column in the dataframe that I am trying to transform.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a numerical vector x, you can use the `asinh()` function:

```
x = seq(-10, 10, 1)
x_ihs = asinh(x)
```

If you want to define your own function to do it manually, use:

```
my_asinh <- function(var) { var_ihs = log(var + sqrt(var^2+1)); return(var_ihs) }
x_ihs2 = my_asinh(x)
```

Why exactly your code does not work is unclear without more information, but hopefully, this answer helps others with the same question.